# File Explorer goes from a shared directory to "Network" after waking from sleep

Tags: networking, windows-10, windows-explorer, shared-folders

When I open a network shared directory with File Explorer, and put the computer into sleep, and then wake it, File Explorer's address is changed to "Network" and a yellow notification bar shows the following message:

"Network discovery and file sharing are turned off. Network computers and devices are not visible. Click to change..."

Can I make File Explorer remain at the same shared directory, in this case?

Comment: This is caused by the powering down of the network hardware during sleep. On return from sleep the operating system becomes active before the driver is called to reinitialise the hardware, giving initial network errors. Unfortunately, keeping the hardware powered (Device Manager setting) does not solve the problem if the network interface is wireless, as the driver and support software also need to run during sleep to keep the connection alive, but all OS activity ceases while sleeping, though an Ethernet connection may be maintained with this setting.

Comment: You could try to minimise Explorer before sleeping, and restore it after the network connection is restored. I am not seeing your symptoms, so I cannot check if this works.

Comment: In my case this is happening on both the laptop (Wi-Fi) and the desktop (Ethernet). I will try to minimise the File Explorer and see if that fixes the problem.